# using firebase admin sdk on a web client

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I need to use the `firebase admin sdk` to authenticate myself on the back-office of my project.

using the `sdk` on the server side is working just fine.

but with a `reactjs` component (a chat component) to chat between web client and a mobile app, the sdk is not working displaying the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function at DatabaseService../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js.DatabaseService.getDatabase

Has anyone tried this before or is it just impossible to use the admin sdk on the web client interface ?

Comment: Use of the Admin SDK in client environments isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson !
I will switch to `token authentication` then :)